# Silverlight App object Does not exist' Error

Tags: silverlight, object, production, sketchflow

> name 'App' does not exist in the current context.

How that possible?
Have to note my initialization code is different than MainPage() type, as I converted SketchFlow app into production Silverlight. They instruct you to do init code via System.Windows.Controls.Frame():

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    this.RootVisual = new System.Windows.Controls.Frame() { Source = new Uri("/MyAppScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative) };

}
public static string ValueFromHome =
"A Value on Home page";
```

the goal was to set up public var inside App object so I can access it from various screens down the road

---

Accessing Resource data requires calling App object I believe as in below, is that correct? so this won't help me

```
string color = App.Current.Resources["customColor"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just storing strings, look into using Resource files. Then they can be translated if that ever becomes necessary.
EDIT (to explain the resource file usage): To access the resource, first create a .resx file in your project (let's say you name it MainResource.resx), change the access modifier drop down to public, add your string with Name: ValueFromHome  and Value:  "A Value on Home page". 
Then you can get the value by adding a using to the namespace of the resource if needed and calling it directly like so:

```
string value = MainResource.ValueFromHome;
```

I'd be wary of static variables hanging around. Maybe you could use a MainViewModel to store that value. If you really need a static variable create a new static class in your project and put your ValueFromHome property in that class. The App probably isn't available since it is a Silverlight construct and not made to be available to all areas.

Comment: No, not storing static data, I need to assign values and retrieve later. So why do I get the App() object error, any idea?

Comment: is this a build or a runtime error? Do you have an app.xaml.cs in your project? It's hard to tell from your description. A few lines of code would probably help.

Comment: Well the codestring color = App.Current.Resources["customColor"].ToString();